# Convert Promise<string[]> to string[]

Tags: typescript, promise

I am calling following function to get a list of saved cards. fetch function return a Promise Object. I want to convert it to a string[] and return. 
Is this a possible thing to do?

```
const fetchSavedCards = (): string[] => {
return fetch("/fetchSavedCards")
    .catch((error: Error) => {
        throw new Error(error.message);
    })
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((cards: string[]) => {
        return cards;
    });

};
```

The returned result set is then need to be displayed in a web page. But .map() function does not work with Promise object.

```
    <CardContent>
    <label> Card Selection  </label>
    <div className="container" id="cards">
        {Service.fetchSavedCards().map(
            (card) => <label>
                <input type="radio" name="selectedCard" value="test" onChange={this.handleCardSelectionChange}/>
                    {card}
            </label>)}
    </div>
    ...
</CardContent>
```

Comment: Why you not use `Promise<string[]>` type, I think it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you can. Consider this:

```js
const fetchSavedCards = (): string[] => {
  const result: string[] = [];

  fetch("/fetchSavedCards")
    .catch((error: Error) => {
        throw new Error(error.message);
    })
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((cards: string[]) => {
        result.length = 0;
        return cards.forEach((item, i) => {
          result[i] = item;
        });
    });

  return result;
};
```

You can of course return the premature `result` array eagerly, then wait for the promise to resolve later and fill-in the element of `result` asynchronously. But is it a desirable solution to you?

Maybe tell us about the real problem you encountered.

Comment: You get an empty array at first. Wait a bit, then check later you'll see it's non-empty. Not sure why you think pass in as param should change anything :-/

Comment: @hackape - I  need to display the returned result set in a web page and I have edited the question with the front-end code. There .map() does not work with Promise object

Comment: @Ruchira Looks like you're using react. Do you use hook API or traditional class component API?

Comment: @hackape - Yes I'm using react and it is a traditional class component API

Answer (score 3):

You want to convert an async function to sync function, that's not a good idea and you can't do that. I guess maybe you just don't know how to use `fetchSavedCards` correctly after you define it like I before.

```js
const fetchSavedCards = (): Promise<string[]> => {
  return fetch("/fetchSavedCards")
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((cards: string[]) => {
        return cards;
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => {
        throw new Error(error.message);
    });
};

// how to use fetchSavedCards correctly
fetchSavedCards().then(cards => handleCards(cards));
```

BTW, it is better to put the `.catch()` in the last.

If you want to use these data to render the view in the react, you should save the returned data in the state, and render the view by state.

Full example (by react hooks):

```js
const fetchSavedCards = (): Promise<string[]> => {
  return fetch('/fetchSavedCards')
    .then(response => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then((cards: string[]) => {
      return cards
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => {
      throw new Error(error.message)
    })
}

function Cards() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState<string[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSavedCards().then(cards => setCards(cards))
  }, [])

  return (
    <CardContent>
      <label> Card Selection </label>
      <div className="container" id="cards">
        {cards.map(card => (
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="selectedCard"
              value="test"
              onChange={this.handleCardSelectionChange}
            />
            {card}
          </label>
        ))}
      </div>
      ...
    </CardContent>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently and wrote this type to help with that

```
export type UnpackPromise<T> = T extends {
    then(onfulfilled?: (value: infer U) => unknown): unknown;
} ? U : never;
```

basically a combination of [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), conditional types and [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html)

in your case I would use the [ReturnType Utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) for the function and call the UnpackPromise type with whatever that returns